# Get records from datatable grouped by date and every two hour

Tags: c#, linq

I have a datatable whose columns are name, code, dateAndTime. Now I want to get the count of all the records for every hour in a Day using LINQ.

DateTime Column contains data as

```
2018-08-01 07:00:06.163
2018-08-01 07:50:11.873
2018-08-01 08:00:42.623
2018-08-01 07:20:48.363
2018-08-01 09:01:15.243
2018-08-01 06:01:16.507
```

Now I want to get the count of all the records from the start of the day to the end of the day hourly basis.

Example would be:
if first record is around 5 Am on 2018-08-01 then its start with 5 AM to 7 Am as first row

```
2018-08-01  7   ( 5 Am - 7 Am) - 36 count
2018-08-01  9   ( 7 Am - 9 Am) - 12 count
2018-08-01  11   ( 9 Am - 11 Am) - 12 count
2018-08-01  13  (11 Am - 1 PM)- 0 count
2018-08-01  15  (1 PM - 3 PM)- 36 count
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far to solve this?

Comment: user `Timer` and `BackgroundWorker/Task.Run(()=>linq)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try out this piece of code:

```
const int groupHours = 2;
const int driftHours = 1;
var dateTimes = new List<DateTime>() { new DateTime(2018, 8, 30, 7, 0, 6), new DateTime(2018, 8, 30, 8, 0, 6) };
var result = dateTimes.GroupBy(d => new DateTime(d.Year, d.Month, d.Day, (((d.Hour - driftHours) / groupHours) + 1) * groupHours + driftHours, 0, 0)).Select(g => new { Key = g.Key, Count = g.Count() });
```

Example of `(((d.Hour - driftHours) / groupHours) + 1) * groupHours + driftHours` for 8 AM:

- substract 1 (hours to drift from regular numbers divisable by 2) from 8 AM = 7 AM
- divide by 2 (hour span in group) and cut off everything after decimal point - how many "groups" there were to this point
- add 1 to previous result to get the **current group**
- multiply by 2 (hour span in group) to get hour for this group
- add 1 (drift) to make 9 out of 8, 11 out of 10 etc

Comment: Szymon Chęciński thank's for this, Its working properly